# What does the operator reassign function/construction return?

Tags: c++

I have the following function/constructor/method (I'm not sure exactly what it is)

```
List<T>& List<T>::operator=(const List<T> &x)
```

where List is a linked list and this is supposed to do assignment.  However, I'm not sure exactly what this is supposed to return.  Eclipse keeps telling me that control reaches end of non-void function; however, I'm not sure exactly what.  I'm new to C++ so keep the answers simple if posssible.  Thanks :)

Comment: You're not returning anything. You need to return something (in this case, probably the new List object).

Comment: Also read [What is the Copy-and-Swap Idiom](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279543/what-is-the-copy-and-swap-idiom) which describes best practices for writing a custom assignment operator.

Comment: `operator==` is not a constructor, because the object you assign to already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually, assignment operators return a reference to the object itself, so just end your function with `return *this;`. Having an assignment expression have the value of the assignee allows you to write things like `a = b = c;` and `if ((a = get_data()) == c)` etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is an overloaded `=` operator to your `List<T>` class, It should return a reference to the class type. Returning a reference allows the return value to act as an l-value and allows its usage in chaining calls like:

```
a = b = c;
```

You should be returning a `*this`.

Explanation of what it is:

```
List<T>& List<T>::operator = (const List<T> &x)
^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^  ^^^^^^^^ ^  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ <------------- Parameter being passed to =
Return Type |         |    |
            |         |    |<------------- operator being overloaded
            |       Keyword operator
         Class whose operator is being overloaded
```

Comment: Unfortunately I could only give 1 accepted answer, otherwise I would have given you one.  However, I up voted you to show my appreciation, anyways...cheers

Comment: @Nosrettap: No worries :) Always accept the answer which helps you in best possible way to solve your problem.